# Append Javascript File to the end of the InlineScript Collection from child view

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm working with Zend Framework 2.

In my Layout File i inject some javascript files like this:

```
$this->InlineScript()
            ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/myfile.js');


echo $this->InlineScript();
```

Now i want to inject some javascript from a view so that it appends to the end of the InlineScript Collection.

So i wrote this in my action view:

```
<?php $this->InlineScript()->offsetSetFile(100,$this->basePath() . '/js/xyz.js'); ?>
```

But the result is the File xyz is loaded first in the rendered view.

I'm working with Zend Framework 2.0.5

Does anybody can give me an advise how to manage this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to complement this old question:

Inside View:
Append a **file** at the top of the page:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/filename.js');
```

Append a **script** at the top the page

```
$this->headScript()->appendScript('alert(1)');
```

Append a **file** at the bottom of the page:

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile('/js/filename.js');
```

Append a **script** at the bottom of the page

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendScript('alert(1)');
```

**Inside Controller/Action**

Grab Headscript using serviceLocator and the rest is the same

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('viewhelpermanager')
    ->get('HeadScript')->appendScript('alert(1)'); //or ->appendFile('/js/filename.js');
```

If you know how to get inlineScrip inside an action please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by using `appendFile` within your layout. Your view script is run first in which you append a script to the stack. Then, when your layout is run, you append again, making the script from your layout the last one. Try to use `prependScript` in your layout file such that the script from your layout is not appended to the already added scripts.

Comment: Yep, i know this, but the problem is the same. I want the javascript file should be loaded as last. But with the mentioned way i couldn't get it work. The same withe the method you mentionend. Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps this is caused by using `appendFile` within your layout. I admit that I am not exactly sure which is executed first, but my guess would be that your view script is run first. In the view script, you append a script to the stack, and when your layout is run, you append again. If this is the order of execution, then your script from your layout will always be the last one. Try to use `prependScript` in your layout file and see if that does the trick.

Comment: hey andy, this works but its not the behavior i would expect. From the logic view i would think the offsetSetFile Method should do this. But anyway.
Thanks for your help. Can you edit your answer, so i can accept it ?

Comment: Done. Logically, you are offsetting the script from your view script. At the time you call `offsetSetFile`, that file is added at the correct "place" _at that time_. However, you are still _appending_ a file in your layout. Appending always appends (you guessed it), regardless of whether or not you used an offset _prior_ to appending. Thus, I don't think the offset is taken into account when outputting the scripts/files. I didn't actually study the source code to back this up, but this is what my logical sense tells me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this explanation could be really useful (I ruined my head with this problem some times ago..)

Let's start with a case :

You have 4 scripts to append in a page.

2 are defined in your layout and 2 in your view.

Let's name them script1, script2, script3 and script4 (final order should respect numerotation).

Layout :

```
<?php
    $this->inlineScript()->prependFile('script2.js')
                         ->prependFile('script1.js');
```

View :

```
<?php
    $this->inlineScript()->appendFile('script3.js')
                         ->appendFile('script4.js');
```

Result :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script4.js"></script>
```

**What's happened ?**

First, the view is processed, scripts (in the view) are appened in the stack, so we have :

`script3` is appended :

```
[script3.js] <--
```

`script4` is appended :

```
[script2.js]
[script3.js] <--
```

Then, the layout is processed, and script are prepended in reverse order so :

`script2` is prepended :

```
[script2.js] <--
[script3.js]
[script4.js]
```

`script1` is prepended :

```
[script1.js] <--
[script2.js]
[script3.js]
[script4.js]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working around the questión : "**If you know how to get inlineScrip inside an action please let us know.**", got a pretty solution and decided to post it here:

1. Create a small class to be called elsewhere to group all your inline scripts, and format them properly to be rendered by layout.phtml template
2. Define a conditional inserting point to inject the full scripts in your final page

(I replace the code 04-05-2016 because original was mistyped)

```
    <?php
        // Filename: /module/MyTools/src/MyTools/Library/Js2ls.php
        namespace MyTools\Library;    
        abstract class Js2l
{
    protected static $inLineJs;
    protected static $inLineVars;

    public static function addSetting($settingkey, $settingvalue)
    {
        if(!self::isSettingThere($settingkey)){
            self::$inLineVars[$settingkey] = $settingvalue;
        }
    }

    public static function addScript($script, $scriptkey=NULL)
    {
        if(!$scriptkey){
            if(!self::$inLineJs){
                self::$inLineJs = array();
                self::$inLineJs[] = $script;
            }elseif(!(in_array($script, self::$inLineJs))){
                self::$inLineJs[] = $script;
            }
        }elseif(!isset(self::$inLineJs[$scriptkey])){
            self::$inLineJs[$scriptkey] = $script;
        }
    }

    protected static function appendItemToSetting($current, $item)
    {
        if($item == $current){ return $current; }
        if(is_array($current)){
            if(!in_array($item, $current)){                
                $current[] = $item;
            }
            return $current;
        }else{
            return [$current, $item];
        }
    }

    public static function extendSetting($settingkey, $settingvalue)
    {
        $current = self::getSetting($settingkey);
        if($current){
            $new = self::appendItemToSetting($current, $settingvalue);
            if( $new !== $current){
                self::$inLineVars[$settingkey] = $new;            
            }
        }else{
            self::addSetting($settingkey, $settingvalue);
        }
    }
    public static function getSetting($settingkey){
        if(self::$inLineVars){
          $sale = isset(self::$inLineVars[$settingkey]) ? self::$inLineVars[$settingkey] : NULL;
          return $sale; 
        }else{
          return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function getScripts(){
      return self::$inLineJs;
    }

    public static function getSettings(){
      return self::$inLineVars;
    }

    public static function iskeyedArray($array)
    {
        $out = FALSE;
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $out = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    protected static function renderInLineJs()
    {
        return (self::$inLineJs) ? implode("\n", self::$inLineJs) : '';
    }

    protected static function renderInLineVars($js)
    {
        $out = '';
        if(is_array($js)){
            $items = [];
            foreach ($js as $key => $value) {
                $items[] = '"'.$key .'": '.self::renderJsItem($value);
            }
            $out .= implode(', ', $items);
        }        
        return $out;
    }

    protected static function renderJsItem($item)
    {
        if(is_scalar($item)){
            return (is_numeric($item)) ? ''.$item : '"'.$item.'"';
        }elseif(is_array($item)){
            if(self::iskeyedArray($item)){
                return '{'. self::renderInLineVars($item).'}';
            }else{
                return (count($item)>0) ? '["'.implode('", "', $item).'"]' : '[ ]';
            }
        }else{
            return '[ ]';
        }
    }

    protected static function isSettingThere($settingkey)
    {
        return ( isset(self::$inLineVars[$settingkey]) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public static function ToString()
    {
        $prefix = "\n".'jQuery.extend(MyTools.settings, {';
        $suffix = '});'."\n";
        $settings = self::renderInLineVars(self::$inLineVars);
        $jsSettings = ($settings) ? $prefix.$settings.$suffix: '';
        $jsMethods = self::renderInLineJs();
        return ($jsMethods) ? $jsSettings."\n".$jsMethods : $jsSettings;
    }
}
    ?>

</code>

Whit this class defined you can add, elsewhere,  global variables to be used by your scripts to a global variable using the code:

<code>

    <?php
    // you are elsewhere in your php code. Write
    use MyTools\Library\Js2l
    Js2l::addSetting($settingkey, $settingvalue);
    // or
    Js2l::extendSetting($variablename, $value);
    // $settingvalue and $value can be scalar o array values
    Js2l::addScript($yourJavaScript, $akeyToAvoidDuplicates);
    ?>

</code>

The class knows how to format the code so you can call it to be injected in the template

<code>
    <?php
    // Filename: /module/Application/view/application/layout/layout.phtml
    ?>

    <?php
    // place this call before the scripts block
    use MyTools\Library\Js2l
    $mysript = Js2l::ToString();
    if ($mysript){
      echo $this->inlineScript()->appendScript($myscript);
    }

</code>
```

Now you have an useful class to insert your inline scripts on demand.